# Insert data with forEach() and Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I currently have this code, which enters data by a `textarea` tag.

[image: textarea]

```
<form class="" action="/registration/instudent/{{id_school}}/{{tag}}" method="post">

<textarea name="emails" ></textarea>            
<button class="btn btn-lg">Send</button>

</form>
```

In my .js file I have the following:

```
router.post('/instudent/:id_school/:tag', isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
  const { id_school, tag} = req.params;
  const { emails } = req.body;

  const uStudent = {
    id_school,
    tag
};

let _emails = emails.split(/\r?\n/);
    _emails.forEach(email => {

        // update uStudent email field
        uStudent.email = email;

        // insert the uStudent
        console.log(uStudent);
        db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', uStudent);
    });
});
```

By sending the data and reviewing it by console, it indicates that everything is going well.

```
{ id_school: '34',tag: '20',email: 'example1@gmail.com' }
{ id_school: '34',tag: '20',email: 'example2@gmail.com' }
```

The problem is when it is saved in the database, it only saves the last email that was inserted.

[image: emailr]

What I try is to save the emails this way:

[image: emailg]

Try changing the .split to .match and it doesn't work out and change the .split in this way but nothing.

```
let _emails = emails.split('/\r?\n/');
let _emails = emails.split(/\n/);
```

I tried to enter the .split into foreach but I can't get it to save correctly in the database.

```
    _emails.forEach(email => {
        let _emails = emails.split(/\r?\n/);
        // update uStudent email field
        uStudent.email = email;

        // insert the uStudent
        console.log(uStudent);
        db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', uStudent);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‍ Maybe you can try this code below :

```js
router.post('/instudent/:id_school/:tag', isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
  const { id_school, tag} = req.params;
  const { emails } = req.body;

  const newStudent = [];

  let _emails = emails.split(/\r?\n/);
    _emails.forEach(email => {
        newStudent.push([id_school, tag, email]);
    });


    var sql = "INSERT INTO date (id_school, tag, emails) VALUES ?";

    db.query(sql, [newStudent], function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.end();
  });
});
```

**Updated:** Or if you **still want to using `query` inside your foreach,** than you can use an example code below :

```
router.post('/instudent/:id_school/:tag', isLoggedIn, async (req,res) => {
  const { id_school, tag} = req.params;
  const { emails } = req.body;

 emails.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(email => {
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO `date` (`id_school`, `tag`, `emails`) VALUES (?,?,?)';
    db.query(sql, [id_school, tag, email], (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', { ...uStudent, email } );
```

Comment: He tried this way: `db.query('INSERT INTO date set ? and email = ?', {uStudent,email});` and `db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', {uStudent,email});` and `db.query('INSERT INTO date set ? email = ?', [uStudent,email]);` but it gives me error `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'uStudent' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered already but I would like to provide an alternative solution.

Inside of the `forEach` loop, try using `await` before the query like so:

```
try {
   await db.query('INSERT INTO date set ?', uStudent);
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err.message);
}
```

I believe this should solve your issue due to the fact that Node.js is an asynchronous platform, which means it will not wait for your database queries to complete (which is most likely why you see the last email added twice).

Adding keyword `await` before the query will force the execution thread to resolve before proceeding to the next query.